# CMake ADD_LIBRARY INTERFACE alternative

Tags: boost, cmake, threadpool, header-only

I am trying to use a header only library ([thread-pool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/)) as a sub project. So in root `CMakeLists.txt` I have

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(thread_pool)
```

inside `thread-pool/CMakeLists.txt`

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(thread-pool)

SET(THREAD_POOL_SOURCES)

ADD_LIBRARY(thread-pool STATIC ${THREAD_POOL_SOURCES})
```

As this is a header only library with no source, it gives error.

> CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target:
>   thread-pool

One solution is to use `ADD_LIBRARY(thread-pool INTERFACE)` but that only works with CMake `3.0` and I've 2.8 installed. I am not asking for a solution on how to upgrade CMake to 3.0 but is there any `alternative way that I can use with CMake 2.6 or 2.8` ?

One way that comes in my mind is to have a fake cpp file with some dummy function and put that in sources, But that will be a bad solution.

Comment: Don't count CMake version like 2.6, 2.8, 3.0. It is more like 2.6, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, ..., 2.8.12, 3.0. They changed the scheme of version numbers. Between 2.8.x and 2.8.x+1 CMake gained several features for every x in 0, 11.

Answer (score 1):

To your original issue, try using

```
set_target_properties(thread-pool PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

Comment: It doesn't need source for the properties to work. I have tested this approach on versions as low as 2.8.10. I suppose it's possible not to work on 2.6, but considering that's going on 6 years old YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have unpacked the library in the `thread-pool` subdirectory in the root of your source directory, and your project structure looks something like this:

```
(root)
 |-- thread-pool
 |   +-- boost
 |       +-- threadpool.hpp
 |-- subproject_A
 |   +-- test.cpp
 +-- CMakeLists.txt
```

you only need to do in the root `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(thread-pool)
...
add_subdirectory(subproject_A)
```

to gain access to the library. Then in `test.cpp`, all you need to do is `#include "boost/threadpool.hpp"` with no relative path.

`add_library` is only required for libraries that have a compiled component, so don't use it.

Comment: But that requires me to add relative paths for all other sub projects that uses thread pool. I cannot just say include threadpool to resolve path automatically

Comment: No, you don't need to add relative paths because cmake searches the subdirectory you added for include files. See my updated answer. Is this how you intend to use your project?